# SQL Append table queries

Tags: sql

I have two tables, say table1 with two rows of data say row11 and row12
and table2 with 3 rows of data sat row21, row22, row23

Can anyone provide me with the SQL to create a query that returns

```
row11
row12
row21
row22
row23
```

Note: I dont want to create a new table just return the data.

Comment: Are your rows identical in structure? (i.e. the same number of columns, with the same type and order?)

Answer (score 34):

Use `UNION ALL`, based on the example data:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

`UNION` removes duplicates - if both tables each had a row whose values were "rowx, 1", the query will return one row, not two.  This also makes `UNION` slower than `UNION ALL`, because `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates.  Know your data, and use appropriately.

Answer (score 8):

```
select * from table1 union select * from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a UNION?

SELECT
Col1,Col2,Col3
FROM
TABLE1

UNION

SELECT
Col1,Col2,Col3
FROM
TABLE2

Are the columns on the two tables identical?

Answer (score 1):

In **MS Access** you can achieve the same goal with an **INSERT INTO** query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
```